# AWS Lambda function unable to use os.system

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Im not sure if its a permission issue but I can't get anything to run with `os.system`. Here is a basic test I have for my Lambda function -

```
import os

def test(event, context):
    print(os.system('ls'))
```

Am I doing something wrong?

*Update*

What Im ultimately trying to do is do a pg_dump of one of my databases to a `/tmp` folder, then save that file in S3, then delete the file in the lambda directory. Here are the logs Im receiving from the test above -

[image]

Comment: os.system shouldn't be used at all, you should use the subprocess module. That said, why it doesn't work? What results do you get? Do you have an error traceback? Please edit the question and add more information

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? As far as you are concerned, there is no `os` or `system` when you run on lambda.

Comment: I updated the question with some more context

Comment: But is there something in the `tmp` folder? Otherwise this is exactly what you would expect. Did you try writing something to it?

Comment: I can read whats in the folder but couldn't run `os.system('rm tmp/my_file')`. I ended up just ditching lambda though and doing it on a server - https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/5md0yd/how_to_lambdafy_this_rds_postgres_db_backup_script/dc2qen4

Comment: I think you are missing a slash as you can only create and remove files in the /tmp location. `os.system('rm /tmp/my_file')`